# RestSharp's deserialization doesn't work, C# Serialization does

Tags: c#, xml, serialization, restsharp

I've got some troubles with RestSharp's builtin deserialization.

My Code:

```
RestClient client = new RestClient("https://example.com/rest/");

client.ClearHandlers();
client.AddHandler("application/xml", new RestSharp.Deserializers.XmlDeserializer());

var request = new RestRequest();
request.Resource = "member/findScoutIdsForOrganization/{organizationId}";
request.AddUrlSegment("organizationId", orgId);

var response = client.Execute<wsScoutIdList>(request);
var scoutids = response.Data;

XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(wsScoutIdList));
var result = serializer.Deserialize(XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(response.Content)));
```

wsScoutIdList.java: (generated by xsd2code++)

```
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.Xml", "4.6.81.0")]
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute("ScoutIdList", Namespace="", IsNullable=false)]
public partial class wsScoutIdList
{

    private List<string> _list;

    public wsScoutIdList()
    {
        this._list = new List<string>();
    }

    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("list", Form=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified, IsNullable=true)]
    public List<string> list
    {
        get
        {
            return this._list;
        }
        set
        {
            this._list = value;
        }
    }
}
```

xml:

```
<?xml version ="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes" ?>
<ScoutIdList>
    <list>id1</list>
    <list>id2</list>
    <list>id3</list>
</ScoutIdList>
```

System.XML.Serialization works, but RestSharp doesn't. The list is simply empty.

I also tried json, not working either.

Answer (score 0):

There are few things:

You don't need this:

```
client.AddHandler("application/xml", new RestSharp.Deserializers.XmlDeserializer());
```

Instead use this:

```
request.RequestFormat = DataFormat.Xml;
```

Also you if a parameter is not in format of parameterName=parameterValue you can't use this:

request.AddUrlSegment("organizationId", orgId);

Instead just do this:

```
request.Resource = "member/findScoutIdsForOrganization/ + orgId";
```

If you want to use default serializer you just can remove this:

```
XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(wsScoutIdList));
```

So your code should look like this:

```
RestClient client = new RestClient("https://example.com/rest/");

request.RequestFormat = DataFormat.Xml;


var request = new RestRequest();
request.Resource = "member/findScoutIdsForOrganization/" + orgId;

var response = client.Execute<wsScoutIdList>(request);
var scoutids = response.Data;
```

Hope it helps

Comment: `request.RequestFormat = DataFormat.Xml;` does not work, it uses json then

`request.AddUrlSegment("organizationId", orgId);` is the recommended way, there's nothing wrong with that.
The extra `XmlSerializer` is only there to show that this one is working. The RestSharper approach is already in there and not working.